# camera frame wait time out_android, MediaCodec, MediaMux,SurfaceTexure

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm trying to change the CameraToMpegTest.java from http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ to a android project. And I meet some trouble, here is the errors from the logcat:

```
12-13 17:19:38.074: E/AndroidRuntime(4929): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 17:19:38.074: E/AndroidRuntime(4929): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.brendon.cameratompeg/com.brendon.cameratompeg.CameraToMpeg}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't stop due to wrong state.
12-13 17:19:38.074: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2918)
12-13 17:19:38.074: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
12-13 17:19:38.074: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
```

The code get wrong at "mStManager.awaitNewImage();", which is in the onResume function. And the logcat says "camera frame wait time out".
mStManager is an instance of the class SurfaceTextureManager. And "camera frame wait time out" comes from the awaitNewImage() function. I've added that class to my post.

Part of my code is like this(The onCreate function and onResume function):

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // arbitrary but popular values
        int encWidth = 640;
        int encHeight = 480;
        int encBitRate = 6000000;      // Mbps
        Log.d(TAG, MIME_TYPE + " output " + encWidth + "x" + encHeight + " @" + encBitRate);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_to_mpeg);

           prepareCamera(encWidth, encHeight);
           prepareEncoder(encWidth, encHeight, encBitRate);
           mInputSurface.makeCurrent();
           prepareSurfaceTexture();

           mCamera.startPreview();         
}


@Override
public void onResume(){

    try {

         long startWhen = System.nanoTime();
           long desiredEnd = startWhen + DURATION_SEC * 1000000000L;
           SurfaceTexture st = mStManager.getSurfaceTexture();
           int frameCount = 0;

        while (System.nanoTime() < desiredEnd) {
            // Feed any pending encoder output into the muxer.
            drainEncoder(false);

            // Switch up the colors every 15 frames.  Besides demonstrating the use of
            // fragment shaders for video editing, this provides a visual indication of
            // the frame rate: if the camera is capturing at 15fps, the colors will change
            // once per second.
            if ((frameCount % 15) == 0) {
                String fragmentShader = null;
                if ((frameCount & 0x01) != 0) {
                    fragmentShader = SWAPPED_FRAGMENT_SHADER;
                }
                mStManager.changeFragmentShader(fragmentShader);
            }
            frameCount++;

            // Acquire a new frame of input, and render it to the Surface.  If we had a
            // GLSurfaceView we could switch EGL contexts and call drawImage() a second
            // time to render it on screen.  The texture can be shared between contexts by
            // passing the GLSurfaceView's EGLContext as eglCreateContext()'s share_context
            // argument.
            mStManager.awaitNewImage();
            mStManager.drawImage();

            // Set the presentation time stamp from the SurfaceTexture's time stamp.  This
            // will be used by MediaMuxer to set the PTS in the video.
            if (VERBOSE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "present: " +
                        ((st.getTimestamp() - startWhen) / 1000000.0) + "ms");
            }
            mInputSurface.setPresentationTime(st.getTimestamp());

            // Submit it to the encoder.  The eglSwapBuffers call will block if the input
            // is full, which would be bad if it stayed full until we dequeued an output
            // buffer (which we can't do, since we're stuck here).  So long as we fully drain
            // the encoder before supplying additional input, the system guarantees that we
            // can supply another frame without blocking.
            if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "sending frame to encoder");
            mInputSurface.swapBuffers();
        }

        // send end-of-stream to encoder, and drain remaining output
        drainEncoder(true);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG,  e.getMessage());
        // release everything we grabbed
        releaseCamera();
        releaseEncoder();
        releaseSurfaceTexture();
    }
}
```

a class in the code that is relevant to the error

```
private static class SurfaceTextureManager
            implements SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener {
        private SurfaceTexture mSurfaceTexture;
        private CameraToMpeg.STextureRender mTextureRender;

        private Object mFrameSyncObject = new Object();     // guards mFrameAvailable
        private boolean mFrameAvailable;

        /**
         * Creates instances of TextureRender and SurfaceTexture.
         */
        public SurfaceTextureManager() {
            mTextureRender = new CameraToMpeg.STextureRender();
            mTextureRender.surfaceCreated();

            if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "textureID=" + mTextureRender.getTextureId());
            mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(mTextureRender.getTextureId());

            // This doesn't work if this object is created on the thread that CTS started for
            // these test cases.
            //
            // The CTS-created thread has a Looper, and the SurfaceTexture constructor will
            // create a Handler that uses it.  The "frame available" message is delivered
            // there, but since we're not a Looper-based thread we'll never see it.  For
            // this to do anything useful, OutputSurface must be created on a thread without
            // a Looper, so that SurfaceTexture uses the main application Looper instead.
            //
            // Java language note: passing "this" out of a constructor is generally unwise,
            // but we should be able to get away with it here.
            mSurfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);
        }

        public void release() {
            // this causes a bunch of warnings that appear harmless but might confuse someone:
            //  W BufferQueue: [unnamed-3997-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned!
            //mSurfaceTexture.release();

            mTextureRender = null;
            mSurfaceTexture = null;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the SurfaceTexture.
         */
        public SurfaceTexture getSurfaceTexture() {
            return mSurfaceTexture;
        }

        /**
         * Replaces the fragment shader.
         */
        public void changeFragmentShader(String fragmentShader) {
            mTextureRender.changeFragmentShader(fragmentShader);
        }

        /**
         * Latches the next buffer into the texture.  Must be called from the thread that created
         * the OutputSurface object.
         */
        public void awaitNewImage() {
            final int TIMEOUT_MS = 2500;

            synchronized (mFrameSyncObject) {
                while (!mFrameAvailable) {
                    try {
                        // Wait for onFrameAvailable() to signal us.  Use a timeout to avoid
                        // stalling the test if it doesn't arrive.
                        mFrameSyncObject.wait(TIMEOUT_MS);
                        if (!mFrameAvailable) {
                            // TODO: if "spurious wakeup", continue while loop
                            throw new RuntimeException("Camera frame wait timed out");
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        // shouldn't happen
                        throw new RuntimeException(ie);
                    }
                }
                mFrameAvailable = false;
            }

            // Latch the data.
            mTextureRender.checkGlError("before updateTexImage");
            mSurfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
        }

        /**
         * Draws the data from SurfaceTexture onto the current EGL surface.
         */
        public void drawImage() {
            mTextureRender.drawFrame(mSurfaceTexture);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture st) {
            if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "new frame available");
            synchronized (mFrameSyncObject) {
                if (mFrameAvailable) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("mFrameAvailable already set, frame could be dropped");
                }
                mFrameAvailable = true;
                mFrameSyncObject.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: You're doing too much in `onResume()`, which is supposed to return quickly.  Long-running tasks like video encoding should not be done on the UI thread -- you need to create a separate thread for it.

Comment: Thanks. I tested a demo before, which put the Mediacodec into the onResume() function. That demo doesn't contain MediaMux so I try to make this one. I never used mutithread before and I just did some research. It seems like I need to do the 'implents runnable' and 'handler' work. Am I right?

Comment: Here's a full project to play with: https://github.com/google/grafika